# IdStreamVCLWin32 not found error in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

My old Delphi 7 application is using `IdStreamVCLWin32` unit in one pas file. This unit is located at following location.

```
C:\Program Files\Indy 10 for Delphi\Source\System\IdStreamVCLWin32.pas
```

When I am running same code in my Delphi XE4 environment, I am getting error `IdStreamVCLWin32` not found.

Note: Delphi 7 is using Indy 10 but Delphi XE4 is using Indy which comes default with it. I have not installed indy explicitly in Delphi XE4 environment.

I searched my entire C drive where Delphi XE4 is installed but found no `IdStreamVCLWin32.pas` file.

How to get rid from this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you were never meant to include that unit directly. The unit `IdStreamVCL` would delegate to either `IdStreamVCLDotNet` or `IdStreamVCLWin32`. And so it appears to me that `IdStreamVCLWin32` is an implementation detail that you are shielded from by using `IdStreamVCL`.

These units have, nowadays, all been coalesced into `IdStreamVCL`. And so you could include that. However, it's not clear to me that you should even do that. Take a look at `IdStream`:

```
unit IdStream;

interface

{$I IdCompilerDefines.inc}

uses
{$IFDEF DOTNET}
  IdStreamNET
{$ELSE}
  IdStreamVCL
{$ENDIF};

type
{$IFDEF DOTNET}
  TIdStreamHelper = TIdStreamHelperNET;
{$ELSE}
  TIdStreamHelper = TIdStreamHelperVCL;
{$ENDIF}

implementation

end.
```

It seems pretty clear that you are meant to use `IdStream` and let the compiler work out whether that implementation is provided by `IdStreamNET` or `IdStreamVCL`.

So, the answer to your question is probably that you should replace your use of `IdStreamVCLWin32` with `IdStream`. Note that the functionality in `IdStream` is implemented differently now. You no longer instantiate an instance of a stream class. The modern Indy offers you a helper class `TIdStreamHelper` which contains class functions. So you end up writing code like this:

```
BytesWritten := TIdStreamHelper.Write(Stream, Bytes, Count);
```

However, I cannot be sure that's the right approach since I don't know what you actually use from `IdStreamVCLWin32`. It's quite plausible that your code uses nothing from there and the use of `IdStreamVCLWin32` is simply a stray hangover from some older version of your code.

So my advice is:

1. Remove `IdStreamVCLWin32` from your uses.
2. Deal with any subsequent compiler errors by studying the code and working out the right way to do it with the current Indy code.

Comment: I included IdStreamVCL, but I am getting error at line idStreamVCL := TIdStreamVCLWin32.Create(fStream); I changed TIdStreamVCLWin32 to TIdStreamHelperVCL in above statement. Then I got error "Too many actual parameters". There is no create method in this class.

Comment: I suggest you do what I suggest in the final part of my updated answer.

Comment: As you suggested, I replaced unit IdStreamVCLWin32 with IdStream and class TIdStreamVCLWin32 with TIdStreamHelper. Now I am getting error at idStreamVCL := TIdStreamHelper.Create(fStream); Error is Too many actual parameters

Comment: No, I suggested removing `IdStreamVCLWin32`, and dealing with the consequences. You don't instantiate `TIdStreamHelper`. Look closely. It's a class that contains only class methods. I've added more to the answer.

Comment: I used TIdStreamHelper class and made some changes to parameters of function calls and that worked!! Thanks David for your help. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @nkp: You should NOT be including ANY `IdStream` units in your `uses` clause, and should NOT be using any `TIdStreamVCL...` or `TIdStreamHelper` classes directly (except maybe in the case of `TIdStreamHelper.Seek()`, which is not wrapped by anything). The `IdGlobal` unit has `WriteTIdBytesToStream()` and `ReadTIdBytesFromStream()` functions (amongst others) that use `TIdStreamHelper` internally.